# CSS: z-index whilst using float: left in image gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float, z-index

I have an image gallery with randomly generated content: The CSS positioning these images is:

```
.item {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

I have some JQuery that randomly selects one of these images in the gallery and doubles its length by using .addClass and following CSS:

```
.frontpageimagelong {
    height: 200px;
    width: 420px;
}
```

Trouble is the longer image gets tucked under the following image. I need to have it cover or appear above the following image.

I thought about using Z-Index as such:

```
.item {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.frontpageimagelong {
height: 200px;
width: 420px;
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
}
```

But this did not change anything. Does anyone have any suggestions on a good way to go about this? Thanks

EDIT: added image of issue:

[image]

Comment: Floating elements *always* show up under positioned elements and *always* show up over non-positioned elements, according to MDN's [rules of stacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_and_float). Maybe try making the long image absolutely positioned?

Comment: can you create  a fiddle reproducing this issue.. It is difficult to say without the HTML..

Comment: Hmm weirdly enough the opposite seems to be happening with me. The positioned image retreats to the back (with 2 images covering it all now) whilst the floated images all come to the front)

Comment: Wait, is the long image on the left or right here? Which is covering which? You indicate that the image on the right is the offending float, but your rules say `float: left`.

Comment: @Sushanth-- heres a link to the site its self in testing mode. The long image is random each time so you may have to refresh it a few times to see it http://clarkeconstructions.com.au/newsite/

Comment: @apsillers in the image above, the long image is top left. The image with the white building and sky is covering the right portion of it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help all. I did not solve the issue as such but I worked around it. I used some JQuery to do find the image to the right of the longimage and then used JQ again to removed the image. So the .item div is still actually there, just has no image in it so is invisible